# Hyper V role manual removal on Windows 2008 R2 SP1

Tags: hyper-v

Junior admin messed up one of the hyper-v servers. Hi tried to uninstall HyperV role for some reason. I never tried to demote HyperV server so I am stuck somewhere in the middle.

HyperV role won't uninstall, I try then after three reboots it says to me that role will not 
uninstall anymore because obviously is fails somewhere. Is there a way to manually uninstall HyperV?

Complete server reinstall is not an option because we don't have access to the server console, RDP only.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If you kept with MS Best Practices and ONLY put the Hyper-V role on that server then the only important files are the .vhd's, snapshots, and the vm config files.  Other then calling Microsoft to help you repair the OS, you could do a install on host over top of itself, and then re-add the VM's.  You'd need IP KVM access though.  I've done remote windows installs over IP KVM to reinstall the OS clean (expanded DVD ISO to C: drive) and it took a few hours.  It won't touch other drivers or most folders as long as there is space on C:.

Comment: We ended reinstalling the system with on site support. Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

Try a system restore from the most recent checkpoint before the mixup.

Comment: Umm... Does W2K8 R2 have system restore? I don't believe it does.

Comment: Yes exactly, it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

First, take a look at C:\windows\logs\cbs\CBS.log to see if you can find the error that's occurring.
One idea would be to disable VT-X in the BIOS which will prevent Hyper-V from starting and that might help.
Good luck.