# Windows Server 2008 R2 Server Manager not working -> mmc.exe crashes with System.IO.FileNotFoundException  -> Hyper-V role guilty

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, endpoint, windows

Since some days ago I can't run the Server Manager, it fails like this:

```
Descripción:
 Stopped working
Firma con problemas:
 Nombre del evento de problema: CLR20r3
 Firma del problema 01: mmc.exe
 Firma del problema 02: 6.1.7600.16385
 Firma del problema 03: 4a5bc808
 Firma del problema 04: System.Management
 Firma del problema 05: 2.0.0.0
 Firma del problema 06: 4ca2baf0
 Firma del problema 07: 32f
 Firma del problema 08: 12b
 Firma del problema 09: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
 Versión del sistema operativo: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.272.7
```

There are other strange syntoms in the SO:

- Hyper-V stopped working as well, fails to load any VM information
- The desktop icons rearrange themselves all the time, and always on boot, after I move them. I use now an app that remembers their position to restore it...
- Windows Update service dissapeared, along with BITS service, I managed to recover them and installed all updates availables today

I'm going nuts looking for information about these errors.

Solutions that didn't work:

- sfc /scannow  Doesn't complain about anything
- All windows updates applied (after recovering missing Windows Update)
- ServerManager.log:

  Only one error all the time:

  Error (Id=0) System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800706D9): No hay más extremos disponibles desde el asignador de extremos. (Excepción de HRESULT: 0x800706D9)
  en Microsoft.Windows.ServerManager.NativeMethods.INetFwPolicy2.IsRuleGroupCurrentlyEnabled(String group)
  en Microsoft.Windows.ServerManager.DirectResult.GetRemoteManagementEnabled()

  In english : "There are no more endpoints available from the endpoint mapper"

Where could I see which is the infamous file that mmc.exe is looking for in that System.IO.FileNotFoundException??

Please, any light on this would be much appreciated...

EDIT: It seems the Hyper-V role is the culprit of server manager not working. Uninstalling it from Powershell makes Server manager work again, but allows to do nothing until reboot. When rebooting it cant remove the role and the server manager fails all over again with the same FileNotFoundException.

EDIT2: Need a way to uninstall Hyper-V Role (even by brute force) or fix it (maybe finding the file missing somehow, ServerManager.log is of no use)

EDIT3: Still waiting for any help leading to solve the problem anyhow.

Comment: Sounds like the OS is a mess.  I'd probably do a new install to be safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I managed to repair the problem months later, and when I was trying to figure out another problem....

After failing to install SQL Server Studio due to WMI problems (its setup was saying that) I discovered the WMIDiag tool to diagnose its problems:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=7684

It logged many problems in WMI, which I followed to this forum thread:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/Vsexpressinstall/thread/632ca405-1c38-405b-9ed3-01785c9f99d1

I ran that script to repair WMI and eureka!! The SQL Server Studio could install and I also recovered my "Server Manager"!!

So if anyone finds himself with an strange error like me (probably not...) it can try that tool and that script maybe.

Cheers to all.

Answer (score 2):

Finally the problem was the Hyper-V role. I remembered that it was the first thing that started to bother with problems.

Using Powershell I did this:

```
 PS C:\Windows\system32>  Get-WindowsFeature

Display Name                                            Name
------------                                            ----
[ ] Active Directory Lightweight Directory Services     ADLDS
[ ] Active Directory Rights Management Services         ADRMS
[ ] Servidor de Active Directory Rights Manageme... ADRMS-Server
[ ] Compatibilidad con la federación de identidades ADRMS-Identity
Get-WindowsFeature : No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado. (Excepción de HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
En línea: 1 Carácter: 20
+  Get-WindowsFeature <<<<
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-WindowsFeature], FileNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.FileNotFoundException,Microsoft.Windows.ServerManager.Commands.GetWindowsFeatureCommand
```

And it was the same IOException that when trying to run de Server Manager, so I though I could try to eliminate the suspicious worng module, the hyper-V:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Remove-WindowsFeature Hyper-V
ADVERTENCIA: [Eliminación] correcta: [Hyper-V] Hyper-V. Debe reiniciar este servidor para finalizar el proceso de eliminación.

Success Restart Needed Exit Code Feature Result
------- -------------- --------- --------------
True    Yes            Succes... {Hyper-V}
```

And now the Server Manager is working again!!!

I'll try to re-add the Hyper-V role but I don't need it , by now...

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: After rebooting it says an error has ocurred configuring Windows, reverting changes. So after rebooting again the Server Manager starts failing the same way. So it can't remove the Hyper-V role properly after reboot... Will look for another solution for the broken role...

Comment: Found the same problem here: http://www.petri.co.il/forums/showthread.php?t=56050  , but no useful answer yet...

Comment: A similar problem with Hyper-V role, the only answer is reinstall the server... http://serverfault.com/questions/246017/hyper-v-role-manual-removal-on-windows-2008-r2-sp1

Answer (score 1):

Use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to see which file the MMC is trying to load.

Comment: Very good suggestion, but the amount of files that try to open mmc.exe is incredibly huge... Which ones should I look for? The ones that says "NO SUCH FILE"(24 of them, all .INI) or "NAME NOT FOUND"(140 of those)... ?

Comment: The last one of the list is "C:\Windows\System32\wbem\wbemcomn.dll" ...

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. For future reference though, you can filter the output of Process Monitor by the result code (`ACCESS DENIED`, `FILE NOT FOUND` and so on).

Comment: The process monitor doesnt show those results when mmc.exe is failing, still trying to find which file is missing from Hyper-V. Probably is also responsible of the error uninstalling the role...

Answer (score 1):

Are you absolutely sure your server hasn't been infected with a virus?

In particular certain strains of the Live Security fake AV malware does things like

- Remove the BITS service
- Remove the Windows Update service
- Remove the Windows Firewall service

Check your registry for executables set to run at start up and login:

```
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
```

In particular, look for executables referred to in %APPDATA% of the user you're usually logged in as. If there are other regular users of this server then you'll need to check their hives too.

Comment: Yes, you pointed in the right direction, this computer was affected by a Virus (Rannoh.Ransom kind) and have to clean and decrypt files because of that.
Probably that virus also removed those services and let the whole system affected.
But the virus is gone now. How can I repair its damages? (without reinstalling)
I would be happy if i could remove the broken role to recover the Server Manager at least...

Comment: It's going to be very difficult to figure out what files have been removed. You could try booting from the Server 2008 installation media and doing a repair install, but make sure you do have backups of everything you might need in case that trashes everything.